# using order by in a sql statement that has except

Tags: sql

I'm trying to order alphabetically the fullname from my query, but I don't know where to put my `order by` statement.

Here is the statement

```
SELECT DISTINCT 
    fullname 
FROM 
    Account 
WHERE
    account_id != ? 
ORDER BY
    firstName 

EXCEPT 

SELECT DISTINCT 
   name_of_friend 
FROM 
   Friend 
WHERE
   account_id = ?
```

Comment: at the end? where you normally put it!

Comment: it says that order by should not be put before except i already tried putting the order by in the end but there is an error that says no firstname found in the name_of_friend

Comment: If you want to order by firstname, that column has to be in the result.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I think you need to change following thing in your code

```
SELECT DISTINCT 
    fullname 
FROM 
    Account 
WHERE
    account_id != ?  

EXCEPT     

SELECT 
   name_of_friend 
FROM 
   Friend 
WHERE
   account_id = ?
ORDER BY
    firstName
```

Comment: `except` implies `distinct` anyway.

Answer (score 0):

In sqlserver database you can do this like..(Sorry don't have 50 points to add comment so added answer)

```
SELECT DISTINCT fullname 
FROM Account 
WHERE account_id != ? 
AND NOT EXISTS (SELECT NULL FROM FRIENDS WHERE ACCOUNT_ID = ?)
ORDER BY firstName
```